# Errors with r-markdown and kableExtra pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, kable, kableextra

````
---
title: "test_kableExtra"
date: "14/12/2018"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: head.tex
---

``` {r table, echo = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

table <- tibble(`Column title` = "lots of very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text ")

kable(table, booktabs = T, caption = "Table title") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "5cm")

```

More text...
````

In head.tex:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
```

I get the error `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`

If I remove `caption = "Table title"`

then I get this output

[image]

I don't understand why:

- the column width has not been changed to 5cm,
- why the text after the code chunk is centred,
- why "\begin{tab..." and "\end{table} is coming up.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `kableExtra::column_spec` function.  When it tries to change the alignment of the table, it makes bad changes to the LaTeX code.

Comment: It looks as though this only happens when the table has a single column.

Comment: Thank you, yes it works with 2 columns

Comment: This has been fixed.  I don't know if it's on CRAN yet, but if not, `devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")` will get you the fixed version.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate this update and fix!